# How to Call Python COM object in .NET C#

Tags: c#, python, .net, com

I am having trouble invoking Python COM objects in C#.NET. Appreciate any help.

I have created a Python COM server as follows:

```
import pythoncom
import sys

class HelloWorldUtilities:

   _reg_desc_ = "Python Test COM Server"
   _reg_progid_ = "Python.TestServer"
   _reg_clsid_ = '{07CCE0CC-EB69-41D6-B6B8-67E5D31AF229}'
   _public_methods_ = ['Hello']
   _public_attrs_ = ['noOfCalls']
   _readonly_attrs_ = ['noOfCalls']

   def __init__(self):
       self.noOfCalls = 0

   def Hello(self,who):
       self.noOfCalls+=1
       return "Hello " + str(who)

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       if "--register" in sys.argv[1:] or "--unregister" in sys.argv[1:]:
       print ("Registering COM Server")
       import win32com.server.register
       win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(HelloWorldUtilities)
   else:
       from win32com.server import localserver
       localserver.serve(['{07CCE0CC-EB69-41D6-B6B8-67E5D31AF229}'])
```

The o/p I get when I register the server is:

```
C:\PythonProjects>python HelloWorldCOM.py --register
Registering COM Server
Requesting elevation and retrying...
Registering COM Server
Registered: Python.TestServer
```

I then run the server as below:

```
C:\PythonProjects>python HelloWorldCOM.py
```

Now, the problem I am having is that I cannot seem to invoke the Python COM object in C#.NET

1. Cannot view the registered COM object in the list of available COM componenets in C# project for example, when I goto References->RightClick-> Add Reference->COM, I do not find the Python COM object here
2. I also tried late binding as follows:

   ```
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           try
           {
               Type typeServer = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Python.TestServer");

           object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeServer, true);

           if (instance != null)
           {
               Type type = instance.GetType();
               string who = "Praveen";
               object[] paramList = { who };

               object objReturn = type.InvokeMember("Hello",
                                                       BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                                                       null,
                                                       instance,
                                                       paramList);
               string result = (string)objReturn;
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

       }
   }
   }
   ```

It seems to get the type of server correctly as in

```
Type typeServer = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Python.TestServer");
```

However the program exits abruptly in the very next line when it executes

```
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeServer, true);
```

No exception is thrown though. The output window shows the following:

```
The program '[2596] TestPyCOM1.vshost.exe' has exited with code 3 (0x3).
```

Appreciate any help on this or if you could let me know of an alternate way of invoking the Python COM object from C#.NET.

Thanks.